# Mirror not work correctly for stl imported file

Tags: mirror

I have a troubleshoot with my blender file. I've upload a stl file in blender and when i apply a mirror modify to X axis i see 2 objects. I tried to change 3d cursor position, but not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By mirroring you don't get two different objects; it's still the same. The point on which your object is mirrored is not the 3D cursor but the origin of the object.
[image: demonstration of cube mirroring]

#### Change the Origin

If you want so set the origin to a specific point, mark the point with the 3D cursor, where you want to set it. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and click on `Origin to 3D Cursor`.
[image: setting the origin]

#### Alternative Way without changing the origin

One property of the Mirror modifier is called `Mirror Object`. Instead of mirroring the object at its own origin it will use the chosen object's.
[image: set Mirror Object]